# Rate of allocation formula

Tags: calculus

I'm not certain what the correct term is for this formula; and so my apologies if the title seems a bit vague.

My question pertains primarily to programming the formula; however for the sake of simplifying the objective; the following scenario applies:

Imagine my bakery has an unlimited quantity of pies. So I advertise that anyone can walk in and grab a pie for free; and so an indeterminate number of people start arriving at my bakery to collect a free pie.

With still an unlimited supply in quantity; I decide that, of all the people to collect a pie (indeterminate amount of people - could be 1, 2, 3 or even 1000000), I want 70% of people to get a blueberry pie, while the other 30% of people get an apple pie.

How would I go about calculating the percentage allocation without knowing the quantity of people that would be collecting a pie?

My thought process is that, I would give a blueberry pie to each person up to the point where 7 people have collected a blueberry pie. For the next 3 people, they'd get an apple pie.

But what if (for argument's sake), only 9 people in total arrive at my bakery? All 9 people would have gotten a blueberry pie, and no one would have gotten an apple pie?

To confuse things even more (*not necessary, quite happy just calculating the rate from a linear / non-random approach*):
What if I don't want to seem too obvious, and with the same rates (70/30) I wish to allocate the pies randomly? (A = blueberry pie, B = apple pie):

So instead of:

```
A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B
```

it may just as well be:

```
A,A,B,A,B,B,A,A,A,A
```

Also, what would be the correct term / name to refer to this type of formula?

Comment: Everyone coming in turns a wheel which is 70% blue and 30% yellow , he or she gets the cake of the color the wheel arrow indicates. Since you have so many people coming in, in the mean you get, what you want, but not in a very short time.